# VBS ReadLine error ÿþH

Tags: string, vbscript, readline, readfile

I am looking to read a txt file and then be able to use that variable in my vb script, but it is not working. if I echo it out to console, it puts out "ÿþH". I do not know what this is. here is my code

```
Const FONTS = &H14&
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FONTS)


FileName = "c:\users\user\desktop\fonts.txt"
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  count = objFile.ReadLine
  Wscript.Echo count    'this outputs "ÿþH" instead of "arial.ttf" from file
  objFoler.CopyHere "c:\users\user\desktop\"& count
Loop
objFile.Close
```

Comment: What happens if you try the following?
`Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading, False, -1)`

Comment: thank you very much. I had used this originally but some reason I took it off. Not sure how to mark as answered though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is probably Unicode, not ASCII.

If you add `Const TristateTrue = -1` to your script, and then call `Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading, TristateTrue)` instead of `Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)`, the file will be opened as Unicode instead of ASCII.

According to the documentation for `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, the `TristateTrue` means the file will be opened as Unicode.